# Azure AD authentication for within the organization and other 3rd party users

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

My app is a react js frontend and .net core back end app. It need to be have Azure AD authentication for the internal users of the organization. But now there is a requirement for allowing outside users to authenticate with the application.

Can I extend my app to do Azure ad authenticate with a 3rd party user with a gmail or facebook or linkedin login?

Or can I use Azure B-C authentication in the same app with Azure AD authentication?

Can someone help me and give me some guidelines on above.

THanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [AD B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider)

> Azure AD B2C supports external identity providers like Facebook,
> Microsoft account, Google, Twitter, and any identity provider that
> supports OAuth 1.0, OAuth 2.0, OpenID Connect, and SAML protocols.

Comment: Will B-C enable internal AD user authentication as well?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

Comment: How to enable B-C authentication for an existing AD? I didn't find any way to do it.

Comment: you can do it other way https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy